# Sublime Text 2 - No 'install' option for plugins

Tags: sublimetext2

After pressing Press Shift + Command + P to bring up the text input, when I type “install” nothing is actually returned in the list of options.

I believe that when I type "install" this should bring up the something similar to a “Package Control: Install Package” option

I cannot install plugins due to this, and was hoping for some help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Package Control must be separate installed first. Instructions are here:

http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control/installation

Comment: The keyboard short ctrl+` is not working, is there an alternative shortcut?